Can't emit message from nextjs app route api
// lib/socket.ts
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
export const socket = io("http://localhost:3000");



// api/socket/route.ts
export const GET = async (req: Request) => {
  try {
    const message = "Store is failed fetchin";  // this will work
    // const message = "Store is failed fetching";  // this will not work

    socket.emit("trigger", { msg: message });

    return NextResponse.json({
      data: result,
    });
  } catch (error: any) {
    const { status = 500, message } = error;
    return getErrorResponse(message, status, error);
  }
};

I have set up nextjs app with a custom server so whenever I try to emit if the text is more than 23 chars it will not work emitting but if it's less than 23 it works why??

if it does not wmit, does it show an error messae. this is something unusual. there might a bug somewhere else
